# What's missing in my WSDL?

Tags: web-services, wsdl, soapui, wsdl2java

Hi I created a web service, and I've been testing it with SoapUI successfully.
But whenever I try to generate the client in Rational Application Developer, Visual Studio or even in SoapUI I keep getting the following error:

```
Using AXIS2_HOME:   C:\Download\Axis2\axis2-1.4.1-bin\axis2-1.4.1
Using JAVA_HOME:    C:\j2sdk1.4.2_04
```

org.apache.axis2.wsdl.codegen.CodeGenerationException: org.apache.axis2.wsdlUnmatchedTypeException: No type was mapped to the name ContractInfo with namespace http://service.invcontractinfo.ws.uig.com/
        at ...

My WSDL is the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?><wsdl:definitions xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:tns="http://wpf.ibm.com/2002/03/models/InvContractInfoWS" xmlns:xsd1="http://service.invcontractinfo.ws.uig.com/" xmlns:xsd2="InvContractInfoWS/sql_GetOwnerInfo/sql_GetOwnerInfoInputs" xmlns:xsd3="InvContractInfoWS/sql_getContractInfo/sql_getContractInfoInputs" xmlns:xsd4="InvContractInfoWS/sql_getDeathBenefits/sql_getDeathBenefitsInputs" xmlns:xsd5="http://Services/Investment_Services/sql_getLastValidDate" xmlns:xsd6="http://generatedschema.bowstreet.com/InvContractInfoWS/GetLastValidDateInputSchema" xmlns:xsd7="http://Services/Investment_Services/sql_getProductType" xmlns:xsd8="InvContractInfoWS/sql_getProductType/sql_getProductTypeInputs" xmlns:xsd9="InvContractInfoWS/sql_getBalanceVariantInfo/sql_getBalanceVariantInfoInputs" xmlns:xsd10="InvContractInfoWS/sql_getBalanceNonVariantInfo/sql_getBalanceNonVariantInfoInputs" xmlns:xsd11="InvContractInfoWS/sql_getTransHistVariant/sql_getTransHistVariantInputs" xmlns:xsd12="InvContractInfoWS/sql_getTransHistNonVariant/sql_getTransHistNonVariantInputs" xmlns:xsd13="http://Services/Investment_Services/sql_getProdList" xmlns:xsd14="InvContractInfoWS/Inv_/InvContractInfoWSGetProductListReservedMethodDispatcher" xmlns:xsd15="http://generatedschema.bowstreet.com/InvContractInfoWS/GetAllContractDataInputSchema" xmlns:xsd16="http://generatedschema.bowstreet.com/InvContractInfoWS/GetAllContractDataOnLastValidDateInputSchema" name="InvContractInfoWS" targetNamespace="http://wpf.ibm.com/2002/03/models/InvContractInfoWS"><wsdl:types><xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:tns="http://service.invcontractinfo.ws.uig.com/" targetNamespace="http://service.invcontractinfo.ws.uig.com/"><xsd:element name="InvestmentContractInputs"><xsd:complexType><xsd:sequence><xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1" ref="tns:CONTRACT_NUM" />
</xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>
</xsd:element>
<xsd:element name="CONTRACT_NUM" type="xsd:string" />
<xsd:complexType name="OwnerInfoType"><xsd:sequence><xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1" name="CONT" nillable="true" type="xsd:string" />
<xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1" name="POL_NUM" nillable="false" type="xsd:decimal" />
<xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1" name="OWNER" nillable="true" type="xsd:string" />
<xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1" name="ADDR1" nillable="true" type="xsd:string" />
<xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1" name="ADDR2" nillable="true" type="xsd:string" />
<xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1" name="ADDR3" nillable="true" type="xsd:string" />
<xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1" name="SOCSEC" nillable="true" type="xsd:string" />
<xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1" name="DOB" nillable="true" type="xsd:string" />
<xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1" name="ANNUITANT" nillable="true" type="xsd:string" />
</xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>
<xsd:complexType name="ContractInfoType"><xsd:sequence><xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1" name="CONT_NUMBER" nillable="true" type="xsd:string" />
<xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1" name="POLICY_NUMBER" nillable="false" type="xsd:decimal" />
<xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1" name="AGENCY" nillable="true" type="xsd:string" />
<xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1" name="EFF_DATE" nillable="true" type="xsd:string" />
<xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1" name="EXP_DATE" nillable="true" type="xsd:string" />
<xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1" name="POL_TYPE" nillable="true" type="xsd:string" />
<xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1" name="PRODUCER" nillable="true" type="xsd:string" />
<xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1" name="WRT_PREMIUM" nillable="true" type="xsd:decimal" />
<xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1" name="POLSTATUS" nillable="true" type="xsd:string" />
<xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1" name="ISSUEDATE" nillable="true" type="xsd:string" />
<xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1" name="PRODNAME" nillable="true" type="xsd:string" />
<xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1" name="QUALPLAN" nillable="false" type="xsd:string" />
</xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>
<xsd:complexType name="DeathBenefitsType"><xsd:sequence><xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1" name="CV_CASHVALUE" nillable="true" type="xsd:decimal" />
<xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1" name="CV_ACCOUNTVAL" nillable="true" type="xsd:decimal" />
<xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1" name="CV_DEATHBEN" nillable="true" type="xsd:decimal" />
<xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1" name="CV_DEATHBEN_ANNIVERSARY" nillable="true" type="xsd:decimal" />
</xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>
<xsd:complexType name="BalanceInfoRowSetType"><xsd:sequence><xsd:element maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0" ref="tns:BalanceInfoRow" />
</xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>
<xsd:element name="BalanceInfoRow"><xsd:complexType><xsd:sequence><xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1" name="CQ_UNITS" nillable="true" type="xsd:decimal" />
<xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1" name="CQ_UNIT_VAL" nillable="true" type="xsd:decimal" />
<xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1" name="CQ_INV_VAL" nillable="true" type="xsd:decimal" />
<xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1" name="AD_DIV_NAME" nillable="true" type="xsd:string" />
</xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>
</xsd:element>
<xsd:complexType name="TransactionHistoryRowSetType"><xsd:sequence><xsd:element maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0" ref="tns:TransactionHistoryRow" />
</xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>
<xsd:element name="TransactionHistoryRow"><xsd:complexType><xsd:sequence><xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1" name="TXN_DATE" nillable="true" type="xsd:string" />
<xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1" name="PY_TXN_TYPE_DESC" nillable="true" type="xsd:string" />
<xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1" name="TD_TXN_DET_AMT" nillable="true" type="xsd:decimal" />
<xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1" name="TD_INT_RATE" nillable="true" type="xsd:decimal" />
</xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>
</xsd:element>
<xsd:element name="InvestmentContractResults" type="tns:InvestmentContractResultsType" />
<xsd:complexType name="InvestmentContractResultsType"><xsd:sequence><xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="OwnerInfo" type="tns:OwnerInfoType" />
<xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="ContractInfo" type="tns:ContractInfoType" />
<xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="DeathBenefits" type="tns:DeathBenefitsType" />
<xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="BalanceInfo" type="tns:BalanceInfoRowSetType" />
<xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="TransactionHistory" type="tns:TransactionHistoryRowSetType" />
</xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>
<xsd:complexType name="MultiInvestmentContractRowSetType"><xsd:sequence><xsd:element maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0" ref="tns:InvestmentContractResultsRow" />
</xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>
<xsd:element name="InvestmentContractResultsRow"><xsd:complexType><xsd:sequence><xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="OwnerInfo" type="tns:OwnerInfoType" />
<xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="ContractInfo" type="tns:ContractInfoType" />
<xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="DeathBenefits" type="tns:DeathBenefitsType" />
<xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="BalanceInfo" type="tns:BalanceInfoRowSetType" />
<xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="TransactionHistory" type="tns:TransactionHistoryRowSetType" />
</xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>
</xsd:element>
</xsd:schema>
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:tns="InvContractInfoWS/sql_GetOwnerInfo/sql_GetOwnerInfoInputs" targetNamespace="InvContractInfoWS/sql_GetOwnerInfo/sql_GetOwnerInfoInputs"><xsd:element name="sql_GetOwnerInfoInputs"><xsd:complexType><xsd:sequence><xsd:element ref="tns:CONTRACT_NUM" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" />
</xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>
</xsd:element>
<xsd:element name="CONTRACT_NUM" type="xsd:string" />
</xsd:schema>
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:tns="InvContractInfoWS/sql_getContractInfo/sql_getContractInfoInputs" targetNamespace="InvContractInfoWS/sql_getContractInfo/sql_getContractInfoInputs"><xsd:element name="sql_getContractInfoInputs"><xsd:complexType><xsd:sequence><xsd:element ref="tns:CONTRACT_NUM" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" />
</xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>
</xsd:element>
<xsd:element name="CONTRACT_NUM" type="xsd:string" />
</xsd:schema>
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:tns="InvContractInfoWS/sql_getDeathBenefits/sql_getDeathBenefitsInputs" targetNamespace="InvContractInfoWS/sql_getDeathBenefits/sql_getDeathBenefitsInputs"><xsd:element name="sql_getDeathBenefitsInputs"><xsd:complexType><xsd:sequence><xsd:element ref="tns:CONTRACT_NUM" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" />
<xsd:element ref="tns:VAL_DATE" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" />
</xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>
</xsd:element>
<xsd:element name="CONTRACT_NUM" type="xsd:string" />
<xsd:element name="VAL_DATE" type="xsd:string" />
</xsd:schema>
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:cns="http://Services/Investment_Services/sql_getLastValidDate" targetNamespace="http://Services/Investment_Services/sql_getLastValidDate" elementFormDefault="qualified" attributeFormDefault="unqualified"><xsd:annotation><xsd:documentation xml:lang="en">Schema automatically generated on "Tuesday, December 7, 2010 2:56:31 PM VET" from the content of XML Variable "getSchema_TransformXml"</xsd:documentation>
</xsd:annotation>
<xsd:element name="RowSet" type="cns:RowSetType" />
<xsd:complexType name="RowSetType"><xsd:sequence><xsd:element ref="cns:Row" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
</xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>
<xsd:element name="Row"><xsd:complexType><xsd:sequence><xsd:element name="CV_VALDATE" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" nillable="true" />
</xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>
</xsd:element>
</xsd:schema>
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:tns="http://generatedschema.bowstreet.com/InvContractInfoWS/GetLastValidDateInputSchema" targetNamespace="http://generatedschema.bowstreet.com/InvContractInfoWS/GetLastValidDateInputSchema"><xsd:element name="arguments"><xsd:complexType><xsd:sequence><xsd:element name="CONTRACT_NUM" type="xsd:string" />
</xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>
</xsd:element>
</xsd:schema>
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:cns="http://Services/Investment_Services/sql_getProductType" targetNamespace="http://Services/Investment_Services/sql_getProductType" elementFormDefault="qualified" attributeFormDefault="unqualified"><xsd:annotation><xsd:documentation xml:lang="en">Schema automatically generated on "Monday, December 6, 2010 4:38:48 PM VET" from the content of XML Variable "getSchema_TransformXml"</xsd:documentation>
</xsd:annotation>
<xsd:element name="RowSet" type="cns:RowSetType" />
<xsd:complexType name="RowSetType"><xsd:sequence><xsd:element ref="cns:Row" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
</xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>
<xsd:element name="Row"><xsd:complexType><xsd:sequence><xsd:element name="PROD_TYPE" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" nillable="true" />
</xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>
</xsd:element>
</xsd:schema>
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:tns="InvContractInfoWS/sql_getProductType/sql_getProductTypeInputs" targetNamespace="InvContractInfoWS/sql_getProductType/sql_getProductTypeInputs"><xsd:element name="sql_getProductTypeInputs"><xsd:complexType><xsd:sequence><xsd:element ref="tns:CONTARCT_NUM" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" />
</xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>
</xsd:element>
<xsd:element name="CONTARCT_NUM" type="xsd:string" />
</xsd:schema>
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:tns="InvContractInfoWS/sql_getBalanceVariantInfo/sql_getBalanceVariantInfoInputs" targetNamespace="InvContractInfoWS/sql_getBalanceVariantInfo/sql_getBalanceVariantInfoInputs"><xsd:element name="sql_getBalanceVariantInfoInputs"><xsd:complexType><xsd:sequence><xsd:element ref="tns:CONTRACT_NUM" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" />
<xsd:element ref="tns:VAL_DATE" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" />
</xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>
</xsd:element>
<xsd:element name="CONTRACT_NUM" type="xsd:string" />
<xsd:element name="VAL_DATE" type="xsd:string" />
</xsd:schema>
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:tns="InvContractInfoWS/sql_getBalanceNonVariantInfo/sql_getBalanceNonVariantInfoInputs" targetNamespace="InvContractInfoWS/sql_getBalanceNonVariantInfo/sql_getBalanceNonVariantInfoInputs"><xsd:element name="sql_getBalanceNonVariantInfoInputs"><xsd:complexType><xsd:sequence><xsd:element ref="tns:CONTRACT_NUM" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" />
<xsd:element ref="tns:VAL_DATE" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" />
</xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>
</xsd:element>
<xsd:element name="CONTRACT_NUM" type="xsd:string" />
<xsd:element name="VAL_DATE" type="xsd:string" />
</xsd:schema>
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:tns="InvContractInfoWS/sql_getTransHistVariant/sql_getTransHistVariantInputs" targetNamespace="InvContractInfoWS/sql_getTransHistVariant/sql_getTransHistVariantInputs"><xsd:element name="sql_getTransHistVariantInputs"><xsd:complexType><xsd:sequence><xsd:element ref="tns:CONTRACT_NUM" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" />
</xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>
</xsd:element>
<xsd:element name="CONTRACT_NUM" type="xsd:string" />
</xsd:schema>
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:tns="InvContractInfoWS/sql_getTransHistNonVariant/sql_getTransHistNonVariantInputs" targetNamespace="InvContractInfoWS/sql_getTransHistNonVariant/sql_getTransHistNonVariantInputs"><xsd:element name="sql_getTransHistNonVariantInputs"><xsd:complexType><xsd:sequence><xsd:element ref="tns:CONTRACT_NUM" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" />
</xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>
</xsd:element>
<xsd:element name="CONTRACT_NUM" type="xsd:string" />
</xsd:schema>
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:cns="http://Services/Investment_Services/sql_getProdList" targetNamespace="http://Services/Investment_Services/sql_getProdList" elementFormDefault="qualified" attributeFormDefault="unqualified"><xsd:annotation><xsd:documentation xml:lang="en">Schema automatically generated on "Monday, December 6, 2010 4:57:00 PM VET" from the content of XML Variable "getSchema_TransformXml"</xsd:documentation>
</xsd:annotation>
<xsd:element name="RowSet" type="cns:RowSetType" />
<xsd:complexType name="RowSetType"><xsd:sequence><xsd:element ref="cns:Row" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
</xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>
<xsd:element name="Row"><xsd:complexType><xsd:sequence><xsd:element name="POL_TYPE_VAL" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" nillable="true" />
<xsd:element name="POL_TYPE_ID" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" nillable="true" />
</xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>
</xsd:element>
</xsd:schema>
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:tns="InvContractInfoWS/Inv_/InvContractInfoWSGetProductListReservedMethodDispatcher" targetNamespace="InvContractInfoWS/Inv_/InvContractInfoWSGetProductListReservedMethodDispatcher"><xsd:element name="reservedMethodDispatcher" type="xsd:string" />
</xsd:schema>
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:tns="http://generatedschema.bowstreet.com/InvContractInfoWS/GetAllContractDataInputSchema" targetNamespace="http://generatedschema.bowstreet.com/InvContractInfoWS/GetAllContractDataInputSchema"><xsd:element name="arguments"><xsd:complexType><xsd:sequence><xsd:element name="CONTRACT_NUM" type="xsd:string" />
<xsd:element name="VAL_DATE" type="xsd:string" />
</xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>
</xsd:element>
</xsd:schema>
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:tns="http://generatedschema.bowstreet.com/InvContractInfoWS/GetAllContractDataOnLastValidDateInputSchema" targetNamespace="http://generatedschema.bowstreet.com/InvContractInfoWS/GetAllContractDataOnLastValidDateInputSchema"><xsd:element name="arguments"><xsd:complexType><xsd:sequence><xsd:element name="CONTRACT_NUM" type="xsd:string" />
</xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>
</xsd:element>
</xsd:schema>
</wsdl:types>
<wsdl:message name="GetOwnerInfoResponse"><wsdl:part name="returnGetOwnerInfoResults" element="xsd1:OwnerInfo" />
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:message name="GetOwnerInfoRequest"><wsdl:part name="sql_GetOwnerInfoInputs" element="xsd2:sql_GetOwnerInfoInputs"><wsdl:documentation>[no description supplied]</wsdl:documentation>
</wsdl:part>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:message name="GetContractInfoResponse"><wsdl:part name="returnGetContractInfoResults" element="xsd1:ContractInfo" />
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:message name="GetContractInfoRequest"><wsdl:part name="sql_getContractInfoInputs" element="xsd3:sql_getContractInfoInputs"><wsdl:documentation>[no description supplied]</wsdl:documentation>
</wsdl:part>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:message name="GetDeathBenefitsResponse"><wsdl:part name="returnGetDeathBenefitsResults" element="xsd1:DeathBenefits" />
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:message name="GetDeathBenefitsRequest"><wsdl:part name="sql_getDeathBenefitsInputs" element="xsd4:sql_getDeathBenefitsInputs"><wsdl:documentation>[no description supplied]</wsdl:documentation>
</wsdl:part>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:message name="GetLastValidDateResponse"><wsdl:part name="returnGetLastValidDateResults" element="xsd5:RowSet" />
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:message name="GetLastValidDateRequest"><wsdl:part name="arguments" element="xsd6:arguments"><wsdl:documentation>[no description supplied]</wsdl:documentation>
</wsdl:part>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:message name="GetProductTypeResponse"><wsdl:part name="returnGetProductTypeResults" element="xsd7:RowSet" />
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:message name="GetProductTypeRequest"><wsdl:part name="sql_getProductTypeInputs" element="xsd8:sql_getProductTypeInputs"><wsdl:documentation>[no description supplied]</wsdl:documentation>
</wsdl:part>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:message name="GetVariantBalanceResponse"><wsdl:part name="returnGetVariantBalanceResults" element="xsd1:BalanceInfo" />
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:message name="GetVariantBalanceRequest"><wsdl:part name="sql_getBalanceVariantInfoInputs" element="xsd9:sql_getBalanceVariantInfoInputs"><wsdl:documentation>[no description supplied]</wsdl:documentation>
</wsdl:part>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:message name="GetNonVariantBalanceResponse"><wsdl:part name="returnGetNonVariantBalanceResults" element="xsd1:BalanceInfo" />
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:message name="GetNonVariantBalanceRequest"><wsdl:part name="sql_getBalanceNonVariantInfoInputs" element="xsd10:sql_getBalanceNonVariantInfoInputs"><wsdl:documentation>[no description supplied]</wsdl:documentation>
</wsdl:part>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:message name="GetVariantTransactionHistoryResponse"><wsdl:part name="returnGetVariantTransactionHistoryResults" element="xsd1:TransactionHistory" />
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:message name="GetVariantTransactionHistoryRequest"><wsdl:part name="sql_getTransHistVariantInputs" element="xsd11:sql_getTransHistVariantInputs"><wsdl:documentation>[no description supplied]</wsdl:documentation>
</wsdl:part>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:message name="GetNonVariantTransactionHistoryResponse"><wsdl:part name="returnGetNonVariantTransactionHistoryResults" element="xsd1:TransactionHistory" />
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:message name="GetNonVariantTransactionHistoryRequest"><wsdl:part name="sql_getTransHistNonVariantInputs" element="xsd12:sql_getTransHistNonVariantInputs"><wsdl:documentation>[no description supplied]</wsdl:documentation>
</wsdl:part>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:message name="GetProductListResponse"><wsdl:part name="returnGetProductListResults" element="xsd13:RowSet" />
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:message name="GetProductListRequest"><wsdl:part name="reservedMethodDispatcher" element="xsd14:reservedMethodDispatcher"><wsdl:documentation>This is a dummy XML input used to support document/literal SOAP encoding for services that have no inputs.</wsdl:documentation>
</wsdl:part>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:message name="GetAllContractDataResponse"><wsdl:part name="returnGetAllContractDataResults" element="xsd1:InvestmentContractResults" />
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:message name="GetAllContractDataRequest"><wsdl:part name="arguments" element="xsd15:arguments"><wsdl:documentation>[no description supplied]</wsdl:documentation>
</wsdl:part>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:message name="GetAllContractDataOnLastValidDateResponse"><wsdl:part name="returnGetAllContractDataOnLastValidDateResults" element="xsd1:InvestmentContractResults" />
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:message name="GetAllContractDataOnLastValidDateRequest"><wsdl:part name="arguments" element="xsd16:arguments"><wsdl:documentation>[no description supplied]</wsdl:documentation>
</wsdl:part>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:portType name="InvContractInfoWSDOCPortType"><wsdl:operation name="GetOwnerInfo"><wsdl:input message="tns:GetOwnerInfoRequest" name="GetOwnerInfoRequest" />
<wsdl:output message="tns:GetOwnerInfoResponse" name="GetOwnerInfoResponse" />
</wsdl:operation>
<wsdl:operation name="GetContractInfo"><wsdl:input message="tns:GetContractInfoRequest" name="GetContractInfoRequest" />
<wsdl:output message="tns:GetContractInfoResponse" name="GetContractInfoResponse" />
</wsdl:operation>
<wsdl:operation name="GetDeathBenefits"><wsdl:input message="tns:GetDeathBenefitsRequest" name="GetDeathBenefitsRequest" />
<wsdl:output message="tns:GetDeathBenefitsResponse" name="GetDeathBenefitsResponse" />
</wsdl:operation>
<wsdl:operation name="GetLastValidDate"><wsdl:input message="tns:GetLastValidDateRequest" name="GetLastValidDateRequest" />
<wsdl:output message="tns:GetLastValidDateResponse" name="GetLastValidDateResponse" />
</wsdl:operation>
<wsdl:operation name="GetProductType"><wsdl:input message="tns:GetProductTypeRequest" name="GetProductTypeRequest" />
<wsdl:output message="tns:GetProductTypeResponse" name="GetProductTypeResponse" />
</wsdl:operation>
<wsdl:operation name="GetVariantBalance"><wsdl:input message="tns:GetVariantBalanceRequest" name="GetVariantBalanceRequest" />
<wsdl:output message="tns:GetVariantBalanceResponse" name="GetVariantBalanceResponse" />
</wsdl:operation>
<wsdl:operation name="GetNonVariantBalance"><wsdl:input message="tns:GetNonVariantBalanceRequest" name="GetNonVariantBalanceRequest" />
<wsdl:output message="tns:GetNonVariantBalanceResponse" name="GetNonVariantBalanceResponse" />
</wsdl:operation>
<wsdl:operation name="GetVariantTransactionHistory"><wsdl:input message="tns:GetVariantTransactionHistoryRequest" name="GetVariantTransactionHistoryRequest" />
<wsdl:output message="tns:GetVariantTransactionHistoryResponse" name="GetVariantTransactionHistoryResponse" />
</wsdl:operation>
<wsdl:operation name="GetNonVariantTransactionHistory"><wsdl:input message="tns:GetNonVariantTransactionHistoryRequest" name="GetNonVariantTransactionHistoryRequest" />
<wsdl:output message="tns:GetNonVariantTransactionHistoryResponse" name="GetNonVariantTransactionHistoryResponse" />
</wsdl:operation>
<wsdl:operation name="GetProductList"><wsdl:input message="tns:GetProductListRequest" name="GetProductListRequest" />
<wsdl:output message="tns:GetProductListResponse" name="GetProductListResponse" />
</wsdl:operation>
<wsdl:operation name="GetAllContractData"><wsdl:input message="tns:GetAllContractDataRequest" name="GetAllContractDataRequest" />
<wsdl:output message="tns:GetAllContractDataResponse" name="GetAllContractDataResponse" />
</wsdl:operation>
<wsdl:operation name="GetAllContractDataOnLastValidDate"><wsdl:input message="tns:GetAllContractDataOnLastValidDateRequest" name="GetAllContractDataOnLastValidDateRequest" />
<wsdl:output message="tns:GetAllContractDataOnLastValidDateResponse" name="GetAllContractDataOnLastValidDateResponse" />
</wsdl:operation>
</wsdl:portType>
<wsdl:binding name="InvContractInfoWSDOCBinding" type="tns:InvContractInfoWSDOCPortType"><soap:binding style="document" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" />
<wsdl:operation name="GetOwnerInfo"><soap:operation soapAction="" style="document" />
<wsdl:input><soap:body use="literal" />
</wsdl:input>
<wsdl:output><soap:body use="literal" />
</wsdl:output>
</wsdl:operation>
<wsdl:operation name="GetContractInfo"><soap:operation soapAction="" style="document" />
<wsdl:input><soap:body use="literal" />
</wsdl:input>
<wsdl:output><soap:body use="literal" />
</wsdl:output>
</wsdl:operation>
<wsdl:operation name="GetDeathBenefits"><soap:operation soapAction="" style="document" />
<wsdl:input><soap:body use="literal" />
</wsdl:input>
<wsdl:output><soap:body use="literal" />
</wsdl:output>
</wsdl:operation>
<wsdl:operation name="GetLastValidDate"><soap:operation soapAction="" style="document" />
<wsdl:input><soap:body use="literal" />
</wsdl:input>
<wsdl:output><soap:body use="literal" />
</wsdl:output>
</wsdl:operation>
<wsdl:operation name="GetProductType"><soap:operation soapAction="" style="document" />
<wsdl:input><soap:body use="literal" />
</wsdl:input>
<wsdl:output><soap:body use="literal" />
</wsdl:output>
</wsdl:operation>
<wsdl:operation name="GetVariantBalance"><soap:operation soapAction="" style="document" />
<wsdl:input><soap:body use="literal" />
</wsdl:input>
<wsdl:output><soap:body use="literal" />
</wsdl:output>
</wsdl:operation>
<wsdl:operation name="GetNonVariantBalance"><soap:operation soapAction="" style="document" />
<wsdl:input><soap:body use="literal" />
</wsdl:input>
<wsdl:output><soap:body use="literal" />
</wsdl:output>
</wsdl:operation>
<wsdl:operation name="GetVariantTransactionHistory"><soap:operation soapAction="" style="document" />
<wsdl:input><soap:body use="literal" />
</wsdl:input>
<wsdl:output><soap:body use="literal" />
</wsdl:output>
</wsdl:operation>
<wsdl:operation name="GetNonVariantTransactionHistory"><soap:operation soapAction="" style="document" />
<wsdl:input><soap:body use="literal" />
</wsdl:input>
<wsdl:output><soap:body use="literal" />
</wsdl:output>
</wsdl:operation>
<wsdl:operation name="GetProductList"><soap:operation soapAction="" style="document" />
<wsdl:input><soap:body use="literal" />
</wsdl:input>
<wsdl:output><soap:body use="literal" />
</wsdl:output>
</wsdl:operation>
<wsdl:operation name="GetAllContractData"><soap:operation soapAction="" style="document" />
<wsdl:input><soap:body use="literal" />
</wsdl:input>
<wsdl:output><soap:body use="literal" />
</wsdl:output>
</wsdl:operation>
<wsdl:operation name="GetAllContractDataOnLastValidDate"><soap:operation soapAction="" style="document" />
<wsdl:input><soap:body use="literal" />
</wsdl:input>
<wsdl:output><soap:body use="literal" />
</wsdl:output>
</wsdl:operation>
</wsdl:binding>
<wsdl:service name="InvContractInfoWS"><wsdl:port name="InvContractInfoWSSOAPDocument" binding="tns:InvContractInfoWSDOCBinding"><soap:address location="http://vmwprocsrvt:9081/UnivInvContractWS/servlet/AxisServlet" />
</wsdl:port>
</wsdl:service>
</wsdl:definitions>
```

For reference this web service was created in WebSphere Portlet Factory.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This WSDL is not valid. At the very least:

> File Untitled8.wsdl is not valid.
>       File Untitled8.wsdl is not valid.
>           attribute 'element' in message part 'returnGetOwnerInfoResults'
>   (message 'GetOwnerInfoResponse')
>   refers to element 'xsd1:OwnerInfo'
>   which is not defined within the WSDL
>   file!
>           Error location: wsdl:definitions / wsdl:message /
>   wsdl:part / @element

This refers to

```
<wsdl:message name="GetOwnerInfoResponse">
    <wsdl:part name="returnGetOwnerInfoResults" element="xsd1:OwnerInfo"/>
</wsdl:message>
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your help. This WSDL was created with a bunch of auto generated schemas with the exception of one schema that I generated manually this one contains the following:
[Schema](http://www.universalpr.com/wps/invcontracts.xsd)

But this schema defines the <xsd:complexType name="OwnerInfoType"> which is used like this: <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="OwnerInfo" type="tns:OwnerInfoType"/> in the <xsd:complexType name="InvestmentContractResultsType">

Is this not well formed?
Do I need to define an OwnerInfo element at the root and reference it with ref="tns:OwnerInfo"?

Comment: @sonar: yes, you do. Only global elements can be referenced globally.

Comment: Yes I fixed the schema thanks to your feedback. Although apparently
I can't give you any votes because I don't have the reputation yet.

Thank you John